# django - building a filter for real estate project

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-haystack

In order to practice what I learnt I started a django project about an real estate website.

The next step is to build the search page where the user can select `multiple filters`, for exemple, `number of rooms`, `baths`, `area`, `city` ...

At the book I read I used a search engines (Sorl with django haystack), so I am wondering if I should use it to filter the user conditions on the DB, or if I should keep it simple using only djando queries with many `ifs`.

What do you suggest me?

Answer (score 5):

I could understand your question partially.

From my personal experience, I would suggest using Django filters.

Consider, If you have the following search filters:

1. Number of rooms in range(ie., min_rooms=2, max_rooms=5)
2. Number of baths in list(ie., baths = [2, 3])
3. Cities in list(ie., cities = [Chennai, Bangalore, Hyderabad])

Then, you can use a single query as

```
search_results = Property.objects.filter(no_of_rooms__gte=min_rooms, no_of_rooms__lte=max_rooms, no_of_bath_rooms__in=baths, city__in=cities)
```

The above query returns properties with all the 3 conditions satisfied(ie., Each of the Property objects will have rooms between 2 to 5, 2 or 3 baths & from Chennai/Bangalore/Hyderabad city)

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.db.models import Q

search_results = Property.objects.filter(Q(room_no=no_of_rooms_val)| Q(bath_room_no=no_of_bath_rooms_val)| Q(area=area_value)| Q(city__exact=city_val))
```

[Detailed explanation of Django Q](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/)

Comment: Please elaborate a bit so the OP can understand why you should do this.

Comment: @Surt Basic filter would return the queryset based on combination of & operator. Q objects can return the queryset based on the combined using the & and | operators.

Comment: @IbrahimK Add explanation about `Q` objects in your answer. That will help the OP to understand your answer. If the given link changes at some point of time, it will not help others.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, but in general I would recommend using Django's filter because it is very powerful.

Let's say the user is selecting options for their house on some form page and you're getting the information with

```
number_of_rooms = request.GET.get('number_of_rooms', 0)
area = request.GET.get('area', 0)
```

You wouldn't need any "ifs", but rather one concise filter query:

```
matching_house = Houses.objects.filter(number_of_rooms__gte=number_of_rooms, area__gte=area)
```

This would return all the houses with at least as many rooms as the user wants, and at least as much area.

You could also allow the user to enter a range for number of rooms and area:

```
min_number_of_rooms = request.GET.get('min_number_of_rooms', 0)
max_number_of_rooms = request.GET.get('max_number_of_rooms', 0)
min_area = request.GET.get('min_area', 0)
max_area = request.GET.get('max_area', 0)
```

And then just extend the filter conditions accordingly:

```
matching_house = Houses.objects.filter(number_of_rooms__gte=min_number_of_rooms, number_of_rooms__lte=max_number_of_rooms, area__gte=min_area, area__lte=max_area)
```

etc.

You can ready more about it in the [Django QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api)